# Order By in Union Nested selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two really long selects that are both nested

```
(SELECT MAX(u.Username) as Identification,max(cht.SentOn) NewestMessage 
from Chats cht 
JOIN(some other select as u that has u.username))

union 

(select Max(GC.Identification)Identification,Min(cht.SentOn) NewestMessage 
from Chats cht 
join(some other select as GC that has GC.Identification))
```

How can I order these (both queries combined into one table results) by `NewestMessage` which is a type of `datetime`?

Comment: We can't read your entire code as currently formatted.  I would suggest instead posting a _minimal_ query.  For example, ditch most of the columns in the select statements, which are irrelevant to your actual question.

Comment: I got rid of the part that was distracting let me know if its still confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would slightly alter your query to:

```sql
SELECT Identification, NewestMessage
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(u.Username) AS Identification, MAX(cht.SentOn) AS NewestMessage
    FROM Chats cht 
    INNER JOIN (some other select as u that has u.username)
    UNION   -- maybe UNION ALL if you don't mind duplicates?
    SELECT MAX(GC.Identification), MIN(cht.SentOn)
    FROM Chats cht
    INNER JOIN (some other select as GC that has GC.Identification)
) t
ORDER BY NewestMessage
```

I am basically replacing your union of tuples to a subquery on a union query, using an `ORDER BY` with the column you want.  Note that aliases in the second half of the union query are not necessary, and in fact will be ignored by SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Add an order by class on the last SQL with the column name on the first SQL.

see my example here: order by TeamId at the end, in this the TeamId is from the first SQL

```
SELECT TeamId, TeamName
  FROM [dbo].[Teams]
union
SELECT PlayerID, FirstName
  FROM [dbo].[Players] 
order by TeamId asc
```